# Flush CPU data caches in Linux kernel module

Tags: c, caching, linux-kernel, powerpc

I have a Linux kernel module which calculates network packet statistics among several CPUs (in kernel address space). Periodically I clear the corresponding memory chunk and strongly need this action to take immediate effect for all CPUs, otherwise it will distort the subsequent statistics values. My target CPU is a Power PC, so its cache coherency is very relaxed. Thus I need to manually flush data caches of all CPUs just after zeroing the memory.

So what should I place just after my clearing procedure:

```
memset(ptr, 0, size);
// what's going here?
```

Comment: All the api about cache and TLB is in [Documentation/cachetlb.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/cachetlb.txt?id=refs/tags/v4.2.1), but I am also wonder which one meets your demand.

Comment: Phrase `need this action to take immediate effect for all CPUs` has no sence for multithread programming. If statistic values are part of some **invariant**, which should be observed by all CPU's, you need to use locking(spinlocks, mutexes) when access them. In some cases *atomic operations* or *memory barriers* provide same garantee with lower costs. There are many other synchronization mechanisms in the Linux kernel. But given information is insufficient for make proper choice.

Comment: Let's assume that we are in deferred interrupt handler on CPU X. There is a chunk of memory responsible for accumulating statistics of ethernet packets received by CPU Y (which is handled by CPU Y). Probably this chunk is copied into the CPU Y data cache. Now we clear this chunk from CPU X and need a guarantee that none of these values (parts of the chunk) will be subsequently incremented by CPU Y. I know that synchronisation is the obvious idea here but it's too expensive for the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reflection I realised that the problem here is not really linked to data cache flushing. Actually I try to avoid a banal race condition (the first cpu clears value while the second increments it). In my case it's too expensive to protect data by mutex, so it's worth using atomic flag to notify the owning CPU to clear the values by itself.